# Delete events from google calendar using api

Tags: php, api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

I'm trying delete events from google calendar using [api](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete):

```
$service->events->delete('primary', 'eventId');
```

And i got this error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
```

I tried too with [api explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/calendar.events.delete) and happens the same error.

Someone knows what's the problem?

Comment: Are you authenticated with the proper user and are you 100% the event ID is valid?

Comment: Have you tried doing events.list first?  this will return a list of events that the authenticated user has on their primary calendar.

Comment: @Morfinismo yes, i think.. i'm using this (only XXXXX..):
eid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: @DaImTo yes, events.list return all correct.

Comment: Just to be sure, a calendar event id should look something like this `6cpm2d1h75i68bb96lgm2j9kcko3abb2ckrm8bb4cgr3ec326gom8db46o` and I´m not really sure how you are obtaining the value but please make sure it does not include any white space at the beginning or at the end.

Comment: @Morfinismo yes. I'm using this (selected value): https://i.stack.imgur.com/086mv.png

Comment: @Juan.Queiroz I see. I give up then. I am not sure why it is failing. The last thing I can recommend you is to try to get the event ID in the "try it" section here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get but please make sure you use the incognito mode in Google Chrome browser and if it works, then try to delete the event here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete using the same incognito mode. If it fails, try using another user and if all of that fails, you can begin pulling off your hair.

Comment: Thank for your time @Morfinismo, but nothing works. Where can i report it?

Comment: Perhaps you can report that here https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request&labels=Type-Enhancement,API-Calendar. Although, before you do so, try creating another project and also make sure you´ve already tried with a different user.

Comment: Thank you, i will do it.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem using python. The two things I did wrong:

- Make sure your scope is set to 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar' not the 'readonly' version
- In python you need to add `.execute()` at the end of your `delete()` call. I bet there is something similar in php?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem when copying the piece of code from the documentation.
Then I noticed that the method knows nothing about the calendar id.

```
$service->events->delete('calendarId', 'eventId');
```

Maybe this helps